# What algorithm opencv GCGRAPH (max flow) is based on?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, graph-theory, max-flow

opencv has an implementation of max-flow algorithm (class `GCGRAPH` in file gcgraph.hpp).  It's [available here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/gcgraph.hpp?rev=5325).

Does anyone know which particular max-flow algorithm is implemented by this class?

Comment: @taocp I'm having trouble reading the algorithm from the implementation, as the implementation is more performance oriented than readability oriented

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out now, but this is the least-readable code I've seen in a while.  Comment your code, folks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not 100% confident about this, but I believe that the algorithm is based on [this research paper describing max-flow algorithms for computer vision](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Papers/pami04.pdf).  Specifically, Section 3 describes a new algorithm for computing maximum flows.

I haven't lined up every detail of the paper's algorithm with the implementation of the algorithm, but many details seem to match:

- The algorithm described works by using a bidirectional search from both s and t, which the implementation is doing as well: for example, there's a comment reading `// grow S & T search trees, find an edge connecting them`.
- The algorithm described keeps track of a set of orphaned nodes, which the variable `std::vector<Vtx*> orphans` seems to track in the implementation.
- The algorithm described works by building up a set of trees and reusing them; the algorithm implementation keeps track of a tree associated with each node.

I hope this helps!